# MySQL return union select results separated in groups

Tags: php, mysql, union

I would like to know if is possible to return the results from UNION grouped by their alias.
For instance:

```
(SELECT * FROM table1) AS first
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table2) AS second
```

so that the result is:

```
first = contains all table1 rows
second = contains all table2 rows
```

Practically i want an associative array like this:

```
[]=>[
    'first'=>[table1 results],
    'second'=>[table2 results]
]
```

I tried it but doesn't work. Maybe i'm doing it bad.
Can this be done with a single query or i've to do 2 separated queries.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with `union` because it removes duplicates.  You can with `union all`.

One way is:

```
SELECT t.*, 0 as which FROM table1 t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.*, 1 FROM table2 t
ORDER BY which;
```

If you don't want to see `which` in the output, use a subquery:

```
select . . .
from (select t.*, 0 as which from table1 t union all
      select t.*, 1 as which from table1 t
     ) t
order by which;
```

Comment: I tried it and it works. Practically this adds a field (witch) to the results, rights ? What is the "t" after table used for ? Thanks.

Comment: The `t` is a table alias.  It is just a short-hand in this case, but sometimes table aliases are needed (such as the `t` after the subquery).